# Will APNS certificate stop triggering notifications?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, code-signing

I have one app available on app store. It is more than 1 year old.
I am using Notifications so I have APNS production certificate.

All distribution certificates and provisioning profiles are expired now.

I want to release an update to the app. Will my notifications break if I release new version by new provisioning profile and distribution certificate?

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Thank you for your reply.  My membership is active. I just want to understand if APNS certificate is dependent on provisioning profile / distribution certificate.

Comment: No, because your app will have same bundle id. New certificate will also work without problems

Comment: yes, if you created the new `distribution certificate` then you need to create the new .pem file, then you need to replace your old pem with new one. your notification will not afffect.

Answer (score 1):

Your notifications will not break if you upload new certificate. 
Suggestion: instead of using APNS Certificate. You can use iOS APNS Auth Key which will be valid till your memebeship is active and moreover it can be used in all the apps which are released under same account. Here are the steps to generate Auth Key,

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your expired apns certificate and update them on the server.